# PowerBi desktop

Tags: excel, relationship, powerbi

I have 2 tables I am trying to create a relationship with in power bi. Both tables have the same values for example:

Table1 has location and Table2 has Location however the location is different. Every time I try to connect them say I need a unique value. Can someone please help me so I can connect them together?

Comment: hi and welcome to S.O. From your public profile, I can see you have not taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) yet. I suggest you do so, then come back and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52560486/edit), giving us more info to help you. You may also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a passage from documentation regarding relationships in Power BI ([Create and manage relationships in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-create-and-manage-relationships). In short, one of the tables you choose for the relationship should have unique values in the join column. So far in Power BI, you can define 1:*, 1:1 and *:1 relationship.

> BlockquoteNote that you'll see an error that states One of the columns must have unique values if none of the tables selected for the relationship has unique values. At least one table in a relationship must have a distinct, unique list of key values, which is a common requirement for all relational database technologies.
>
> If you encounter that error, there are a couple ways to fix the issue:
>
> Use "Remove Duplicate Rows" to create a column with unique values. The drawback to this approach is that you will lose information when duplicate rows are removed, and often a key (row) is duplicated for good reason.
>
> Add an intermediary table made of the list of distinct key values to the model, which will then be linked to both original columns in the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

One of your table has to have unique values in Location (Primary Key) while the other can have duplicate values in Location (Foreign Key). Plus, the table with duplicates (the fact normally) must have values that are present in the other table (in the dimension).

In my opinion, to match your needs, you hshould add all the possible location in the table which would have unique values (the dimension).

I hope I made myself clear.